# Display extra view controller without removing the tab bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My app has a menu and a `UITabBarController`. What I want to do is to display a view controller that belongs to my menu but not to the `UITabBarController`, However I don't want to remove the `UITabBarController`. I tried codes similar to the one below but they are removing the `UITabBarController`.

```
tabBarViewController.selectedViewController?.presentViewController(ExtraViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do it is to use `UINavigationController`. You can create new one programmatically and put your menu controller as root.

And if you put this `UINavigationController` as one of views in `UITabBarController` then you can preform a code like:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ExtraViewController animated:NO];
```

Also you can use storyboard to create your controllers hierarchy like that:

[image]

To do that select your menu controller and go to `Xcode menu>Editor>Embed in>Navigation Controller` and then `Xcode menu>Editor>Embed in>Tab Bar Controller`.

Answer (score 2):

You should get `UINavigationController` of selected `ViewController` and then push view you want to present. Otherwise you are presenting modal view controller with `presentViewController` witch hides your `UITabBarController` view.
Im not at my computer right now, and cant post any code, but hope this helps.